# how to extract min and max rows of data frame and draw multiple graph in a lay out using R

Tags: r

I want to extract data row associated with min and max from 4 data set.

I already coded to check result of min and max using data set.

#Question

1. I want to show result to extract min and max of X1.frac, X1.frac1 and X1.frac2 rows per each time(945, 955, 965, 975)

   ##expected result##

   1. example - fracdata_test_min.csv(Min)

   | time | frac | time | Value |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 945 | 0.904265 | 945 | Min |
   | 955 | 0.919962 | 955 | Min |
   | 965 | 0.920854 | 965 | Min |
   | 975 | 0.925369 | 975 | Min |

   2. example - fracdata_test_max.csv(Max)

   | time | frac | time | Value |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 945 | 0.965208 | 945 | Min |
   | 955 | 0.995463 | 955 | Min |
   | 965 | 0.982396 | 965 | Min |
   | 975 | 0.973242 | 975 | Min |
2. I want show result for df_cv_min, df_cv_mean, df_cv_max using one graph.

   ```
   ### my code

   library(tidyverse)
   library(ggplot2)
   library(reshape2) 
   library(cowplot) 

   df=read.csv("D:/fracdata_test.csv",header = T)

   ##---------------------------time interval (10) 
   int=df %>% select(X1.time.1) %>% slice(2) %>% as.numeric()-df %>% select(X1.time) %>% slice(1) %>% as.numeric() 

   ##---------------------------max time value (10935) 
   time_max=df %>% select(X1.time.1) %>% as.matrix() %>% max() 
   ##---------------------------min time value (945) 
   time_min=df %>% select(X1.time.1) %>% as.matrix() %>% min() 
   ##---------------------------number_time_point (1000) 
   ntp=(time_max-time_min)/int+1 
   ##---------------------------number_measurement 
   n_meas=df %>% nrow()/ntp 
   ##---------------------------Measurement_Encoding 
   Meas=gl(n_meas,ntp) 
   ##--------------------------Add Measurement_Encoding into the main dataset 
   df=cbind(df,Meas) %>% mutate(Meas=factor(Meas)) 
   ##---------------------------Plotting 
   y_min=df %>% select(X1.frac.1) %>% as.matrix() %>% min() 
   y_max=df %>% select(X1.frac.1) %>% as.matrix() %>% max() 

   df_cv=df %>% dcast(Meas~time, value.var="X1.frac.1") %>% select(-Meas)
   ##------------time 
   time=seq(time_min, time_max, int) 
   ##------------Mean data 
   df_cv_mean=df_cv %>% apply(.,2,function(x)mean(x)) %>% data.frame() %>% set_names("frac") %>% mutate(time=time, Value="Mean") 
   ##------------Min data 
   df_cv_min=df_cv %>% apply(.,2,function(x)min(x)) %>% data.frame() %>% set_names("frac") %>% mutate(time=time, Value="Min") 

   ##------------Max data 
   df_cv_max=df_cv %>% apply(.,2,function(x)max(x)) %>% data.frame() %>% set_names("frac") %>% mutate(time=time, Value="Max") 

   ##-----------Merging three data 
   df_3data=rbind(df_cv_mean, df_cv_min, df_cv_max) %>% mutate(Value=factor(Value)) 
   ##-----------Plotting df_3data 
   Plot_B=df_3data %>% ggplot(.,aes(x=time, y=frac))+geom_line(aes(group=Value, color=Value))+ geom_smooth(method="auto",aes(group=Value,color=Value))+ scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","blue","orange"))+ scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:8000*1000,limits=c(time_min,time_max)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=0:8000*0.1,limits=c(y_min,y_max)) + theme_classic()+labs(subtitle = "B. Original data (mean, min, max values)")
   ```

#Data set(test.csv)

| X1.time | X1.frac | X1.time.1 | X1.frac.1 | X1.time.2 | X1.frac.2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 945 | 0.937752593 | 945 | 0.965208348 | 945 | 0.904265228 |
| 955 | 0.959463167 | 955 | 0.954415107 | 955 | 0.919962471 |
| 965 | 0.982386049 | 965 | 0.959723958 | 965 | 0.920854173 |
| 975 | 0.973241841 | 975 | 0.925369792 | 975 | 0.928773106 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the data in long format for `'frac'` columns and get `min` and `max` value for every `X1.time` value.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains('frac')) %>%
  group_by(X1.time) %>%
  summarise(min_value = min(value), 
            max_value = max(value))

#  X1.time min_value max_value
#    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     945     0.904     0.965
#2     955     0.920     0.959
#3     965     0.921     0.982
#4     975     0.925     0.973
```

Another option is to use `rowwise` :

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  transmute(X1.time, 
            min_value = min(c_across(contains('frac'))), 
            max_value = max(c_across(contains('frac')))) %>%
  ungroup
```

**data**

It is helpful if you share data in a reproducble format which is easier to copy.

```
df <- structure(list(X1.time = c(945, 955, 965, 975), X1.frac = c(0.937752593, 
0.959463167, 0.982386049, 0.973241841), X1.time.1 = c(945, 955, 
965, 975), X1.frac.1 = c(0.965208348, 0.954415107, 0.959723958, 
0.925369792), X1.time.2 = c(945, 955, 965, 975), X1.frac.2 = c(0.904265228, 
0.919962471, 0.920854173, 0.928773106)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), 
class = "data.frame")
```